Prevent Next.js from pre compiling certain files
I have next.js project which is used as frontend and a golang project which is used as the backend.
To share config between the two, I use a config file, lets say config.toml.
In the next.js project, there is a page, similar to a settings page where I can modify the details of the config file via the golang backend using a REST api.
Now the issue I am facing is how to use the updated config in the next.js website, as it contains some details like SEO metadata. The config file is already pre built into the next.js build output.
So, how do I go about it? I want to prevent next.js from compiling my one file which contains the loading logic.
load-config.ts
"use server";

import { readFileSync as read } from "fs";
import { parse } from "smol-toml";

import { configSchema } from "./schema";

// This gets pre built and fixed.
const cfg = configSchema.parse(parse(read("/data/config.toml", { encoding: "utf-8" })));

export async function getConfig() {
  return cfg;
}

Note: Using next.js version 14.2.4 and app router

Which version of Next are you using (pages or app router?)

version 14 (app router)
